# WCF net.tcp connection access to other domain user in intranet

Tags: wcf

wcf service running with Net.tcp protocol binding running in server. Then we get one client laptop from other domain connected to our lan by vpn. Then from this laptop we are not able to consume wcf service.
The error it shows like "the remote machined aborted the connection.

Please help on this.

Regards,
Ratikanta

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is make sure that you can connect to a non-VPN network. If it works, you should check the configuration of the VPN network rather than WCF.

As far as I know, DCHP and dynamic DNS updates can be used when a VPN is connected. As a result of their update, the local configuration of the computer will be changed and a new IP address will be obtained, but the local domain name will not be changed. From TCP's point of view, this has to do with credentials, network access security.

My suggestion is that you should prioritize VPN credentials and network access and other configuration issues over WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in the `Web.config` of the server-side code and do the same configuration on the client side; it will resolve the issue.

```
<security mode="None">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
  <message clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>
```